# Strange behavior with 960 Grid System

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I was building a layout based on the [960 Grid System](http://960.gs). I like the fixed (px) version but would like to go with the fluid (%) version and wrap a fix sized div around it.

The problem is that this doesn't work on all browsers:

- FF 7: works
- IE6 - 9: works
- Chrome: **sucks**
- Safari: **sucks**
- iPad/iPhone: **sucks**
- Opera: **sucks**

To see what I mean i made a [small page](http://revaxarts-themes.com/gridsystem/). Click the switch button to change to relative. It should look the same but doesn't :(

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are rounding issues (margin seems to be 4px instead of 5).

Another hint: You print `%20` between the DIVs which get usually ignored between block-elements, but not between inline-elements.

set margin to 0.6% and remove the whitespace.

Comment: Have your take a look with a webkit browser? The 1px doesn't bother me

Comment: AFAIK (and I know well) Chrome is a WebKit browser. I tried Chrome and FF 7. (btw: 1px per margin makes 32px margin difference over 16 columms. Take a ruler and measure.)